# Is english.stackexchange the right place for asking about using references?

Tags: discussion

I've browsed through stackexchange's collection of websites but can't decide where to ask about using APA format for referencing online resources.

This place seems to be the closest, IMO. Am I right? Can someone please point me in to the right direction.

Comment: Here's a [page](http://lib.trinity.edu/research/citing/apaelectronicsources.pdf) which addresses *APA Style for Electronic Sources*. But your best source is the [horse's mouth](http://www.apastyle.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com) is your best bet. Check out their FAQ to be certain. I have seen APA and other style questions there before.